# How to distribute a Tensorflow/TFLearn model on Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark

I'm trying to run distributed image classification in Tensorflow according to this model:[TFLearn MNIST Example](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py). Unfortunately my dataset is to large to be reliably computed on a single machine. So I'm trying to move the model and dataset onto worker nodes.

```
# Initialize Spark
sc_name = "MNIST"
sc_master = "local[*]"
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(sc_name).setMaster(sc_master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

#Import TF/TFLearn
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import tensorflow as tf

import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

# Model to be run on workers
def build_graph(X):
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
        network = input_data(shape=[None, 28, 28, 1], name='input')
        network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu', regularizer="L2")
        network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
        network = local_response_normalization(network)
        network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu', regularizer="L2")
        network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
        network = local_response_normalization(network)
        network = fully_connected(network, 128, activation='tanh')
        network = dropout(network, 0.8)
        network = fully_connected(network, 256, activation='tanh')
        network = dropout(network, 0.8)
        network = fully_connected(network, 10, activation='softmax')
        network = regression(network, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01,
                             loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='target')

        # Training
        model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            model.fit({'input': X}, {'target': Y}, n_epoch=20,
                   validation_set=({'input': testX}, {'target': testY}),
                   snapshot_step=100, show_metric=True, run_id='convnet_mnist')

# Data loading and preprocessing
import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist
X, Y, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)
X = X.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
testX = testX.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])

#Run model on data
rdd = sc.parallelize(X)
rdd.map(build_graph).collect()
```

This gives me the error:
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (28, 28, 1) for Tensor 'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28, 1)'

Which I doubt is the actual problem, as X_train is of shape (55000, 28, 28, 1)

I believe that the problem is that I either haven't parallelized the model or the data properly. If I am fundamentally misunderstanding how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Functions which is passed to map is called for each record separately. So all that `build_graph` sees is a single record of shape `(28, 28, 1)`.

Comment: So you basically try to create N models, and since `build_graph` doesn't return the model, discard them.

Comment: Turning the array into a list of sub-tensors fixed the issue. For example, from [10000, 28, 28,1] to [10, 1000, 28, 28,1] . Spark then properly parallelizes a tensor of [1000, 28, 28, 1] to each worker.

Comment: @DavidOtt I'm glad and grateful you were able to fix the issue. You can answer you own question below to make the question show up as the answered status. People often overlook the comments section